# Is there any way to look for new messages in server without polling?

Tags: c#, jquery, azure

My project is a ASP.NET MVC3 application hosted in the Azure environment. I want to show new messages for a user as it arrives without reloading the page. I can use Javascript to do polling at regular interval and pull messages from server, but my client is worried that it will make their server slow if 10000 users poll at some interval.

I thought (not gone too much into) of using Microsoft push notification service, but I think it can be used only with windows phone.

Is there any way i can do push messaging?

Comment: Hope this will help:http://java.dzone.com/articles/pushing-notifications-azure

Comment: Does anyone knows whether Microsoft push notification service can be used with jquery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options are:

- SignalR
- Websockets

Likely you want SignalR in your application. You can grab it as a Nuget package:

> **Install-Package SignalR**

The definition of SignalR: *Pushing data from the server to the client (not just browser clients) has always been a tough problem. SignalR makes it dead easy and handles all the heavy lifting for you*.

Something else: you're on Windows Azure. You can always scale out/up if needed. The new preview portal makes that dead simple when making use of Windows Azure Web Sites.

Comment: yes, we can scale up and down in azure and we are doing that for other purposes but client don't want to scale up for polling.

Comment: If it's not important enough for your client to do so then polling isn't important either for him.

Comment: Watch out if you plan to scale out your application while using SignalR. SignalR doesn't support web farms (multiple instances) by default. You will need to change the messaging layer (to Service Bus or Redis) in order to get web farms support: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Azure-service-bus

Comment: Do WebSockets actually work when hosting SignalR on Azure? I thought that the HTTP input endpoint wouldn't allow a TCP connection, and you can't bind a TCP input endpoint to a website.

Comment: @RichardAstbury it's true that a WebRole cannot use a TCP input endpoint. But, you can use longpolling in SignalR, which will simply go over the HTTP endpoint. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882442.aspx

Comment: So you're _kind_ of back to polling really! I personally think that email is probably the best push notification out there...

Comment: @XIII: is this SignalR compatible with IE 8 ?

Comment: SignalR is not a best solution here, because websockets will be available from ie10 only and it requires iis8.

Comment: @SujithKp SignalR is not only websockets.

Answer (score 3):

I've had much success with Pubnub: http://www.pubnub.com/

You can easily push messages to javascript or c# based clients. They have a generous free account to try out. It was much less work to set up and scale horizontally than SignalR.

Comment: great, but I don't think my client will be ready to use another third party service.